# Android drawable path is empty

Tags: android, icons

By default no icons are available in drawable app path.
Could anyone suggest me a link where I can find a good Android icons pack to use for my apps?
thx

[image]

How can I do to import default drawable icons?

Comment: The folder will remain empty, if you don't put anything inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ic_favorite_black_48dp paste this icon image in res/drawable folder.

See this links as reference for some standard icons.
[Find here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#)

Comment: I think I found it using "@android:drawable/..." instead of  "@drawable/"

Comment: Yes you can find android system provided icons as android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" this way

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Sorry for the beginner question... Drawable isn't a prepopulated folder but it is empty by default and you can fill it with images, icons just copying them inside that folder.